# GPG4Win + Enigmail = The key ID <email address> configured for the current identity does not yield a usable OpenPGP key. How to resolve?

Tags: gnupg, enigmail

I am setting up a Windows computer with PGP - GPG4Win, Thunderbird, Enigmail. Everything works successfully, until I am trying to encrypt a message. This error message appears:

> The key ID  configured for the current identity does not yield a usable OpenPGP key.
>
> Please ensure that you have a valid, not expired OpenPGP key and that your account setting point to that key.
>
> If your key is not expired, then check if you did set Owner trust to full or ultimate.

Things that work:

- Decrypting email
- Sending unencrypted email
- Generating new key pairs
- Importing keys
- Exporting keys

What doesn't work:

- Sending encrypted

System details:

- Windows 7
- Enigmail (latest release)
- Thunderbird (latest release)
- GPG4WIN (latest release)

Comment: Did you generate a key?

Comment: Hi Angel - yes, we generated keys, and am able to decrypt encrypted mails, just not send. Thanks

Comment: Any other ideas? I can't find this error message anywhere else on the internet. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out.

It is done via the email account settings. Right click myemail@domain.com, choose settings. Then select openPGP Security. Select use specific PGP Key ID. Select the key you want to use for this email account.

Hope it helps.

[image: Screen Shot of email account settings]

Comment: Just a little heads up: People won't be able to do anything bad when they know your key ID, except for figure out your email address.